# NullPointerException in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, boxlayout

Does anybody have an idea how I could start debugging this error in Java Swing?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.preferredLayoutSize(BoxLayout.java:282)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Container.java:1599)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Container.java:1584)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1636)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.layoutContainer(BorderLayout.java:804)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(SynthTabbedPaneUI.java:491)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2384)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(SynthTabbedPaneUI.java:498)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:558)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.access$2000(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:37)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mouseMoved(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3645)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6333)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3285)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6057)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4251)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

It is thrown from this method in `BoxLayout` (line `size = ...`)

```
public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
Dimension size;
synchronized(this) {
    checkContainer(target);
    checkRequests();
    size = new Dimension(xTotal.preferred, yTotal.preferred);
}
```

Comment: Where is xTotal and yTotal initialized?

Comment: this error is from GUI startUp or when you switch ... RTM +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending a layout manager to provide synchronization is unlikely to be effective. Verify that *all* GUI components are constructed on the [the event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Likewise, verify that *all* data models are updated on the [the event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), using either [`invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [`SwingWorker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725). As failures can be obscure, this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513) posed by [@mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) examines ways to find EDT violations programmatically.

Comment: I think I use `invokeLater` whenever I'm adding components or editing them, but not when updating models. I thought it wasn't needed there.

Comment: "Note that it safe to mutate the tableModel from inside the process method because it is invoked on the _Event Dispatch Thread_."—[SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: trashgod just revalidate() + repaint(); repaint will create EDT by default, isn't it, but this thread isn't clear for me, OPs and every posts are shots to the dark, because unvisible container always return null, just getPrefferedSize can returns that, my view nothing to your kind person :-) for alternative +1

Comment: @mKorbel: Thanks for commenting; no offense taken. @Bart: Yes, models fire events to update the corresponding view, and that _must_ happen on the EDT.

Comment: Well I found it, though it was non-obvious. First I moved everything to the EDT, which didn't help. Then I found out that my custom list model (for a list inside a `BoxLayout` container) threw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `getElementAt` (I extended `DefaultListModel`, but should've extended `AbstractListModel` instead) which Swing apparently couldn't cope with, and which caused the errors further down the line.

Comment: Glad you fond it! See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683952/java-swing-jmenubar-sometimes-doesnt-show-up/6686168#6686168) on uncaught exceptions and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728025/how-do-i-turn-a-java-dequet-into-a-defaultlistmodel/6729087#6729087) on `AbstractListModel`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to that line, then it is likely that xTotal.preferred is null, or yTotal.preferred is null.

Comment: Obviously :p But that doesn't really help.

Comment: You asked how you could start debugging... this is the start :) What I would do is set a breakpoint there, and then inspect the variables. If either is null, then you need to track back to where those are initialized and figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

From the amount of code I can see, I would guess that you are trying to do stuff with swing coponents without using an [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)..

This causes ugly exceptions like the one above. I had this issue in a project and I realized it too late to be able to fix it so I just put every thing in try cat and did not print the entire stack trace...

If this is indeed the problem you can possibly catch and ignore null pointer exceptions..

Best approach is to use the event dispatch threads

Comment: P.s I believe your code might still be fucntional and the dimension might be created afterall as long as the exception does not stop the execution... I might be completely wrong as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the error happens "within" Swing (only `java*` classes on the stack trace), I'd take a very close look at my code to make sure all my Swing calls happen on the [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).