# How do I turn a Java Deque<T> into a DefaultListModel?

Tags: java, containers, defaultlistmodel

I wrote a class (let's call it Model.java) that contains a `Deque<T>`, with methods for enqueuing and dequeuing items.  Now I'm trying to tie this to a GUI JList.  I'm baffled by how to somehow use my "model" data -- the Deque -- as a DefaultListModel that JList wants.  I'm still struggling to really get OO concepts, as they apply to GUI programming.  DefaultListModel documentation states:

> This class loosely implements the java.util.Vector API, in that it implements the 1.1.x version of java.util.Vector, has no collection class support, and notifies the ListDataListeners when changes occur. Presently it delegates to a Vector ....

Is there some way to get the DefaultListModel to use my `Deque<T>` instead of a Vector, thus allowing my Model.java code to remain largely unchanged while providing all the listening/notifying behavior for free?  Or do I have to rewrite Model.java to use a DefaultListModel instead of `Deque<T>`?

Comment: +1 Good beginner question.  And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the `JList` constructor takes a `ListModel` (an interface), not a `DefaultListModel` (an implementation).  This is an OO principle (Contract) specifying that `JList` can use ANY object that happens to implement the `ListModel` interface.  From the Java tutorial on [Object Oriented Programming Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/):

> An interface is a contract between a class and the outside world. When
>   a class implements an interface, it promises to provide the behavior
>   published by that interface.

Since `ListModel` has only four methods, it should be very easy for your class to implement them and delegate the operations to your internal `Deque`.  Your class should be declared as

```
public class Model implements ListModel
{
     ....
```

and will contain four additional methods that implement the methods of `ListModel`.  The implementations can do whatever you need under the covers, but must adhere to the definition of `ListModel` and whatever behavior is specified as part of the `ListModel` contract, in the JavaDoc.

Once you have done this, you can construct a `JList` passing an instance of your class `Model` to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks - that is very helpful.  Does this really mean that, as long as I provide an AddListDataListener() method, I don't need to be concerned with deciding when or how to "tell" the listeners that a significant change has occurred to my Deque?

Comment: Okay - I declared my model class as implementing ListModel, and inserted the four method stubs.  getSize() and getElementAt() were easy to implement, but I didn't know what to do for addListDataListener() so I left it empty.  Consequently, although I was able to add an object to my deque, and later retrieve it, it didn't appear in the GUI.  Reading the doc, I see that it is MY responsibility to send ListDataEvents to ListDataListeners.  So I presume that I actually must implement _another_ list, just to hold and traverse my Listeners?  And send them Events when I change things?  Wow.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  If your class doesn't extend anything else, you could instead extend `DefaultListModel` (which would get you the `implements ListModel` automatically) and then delegate listener handling to it. If the default implementation is compatible with everything else your class does, just leave those methods out of your class altogether and the superclass implementation will get called.  You will still have to notify the listeners on change, however.

Comment: I took @trashgod and @Chris's suggestion and implemented AbstractListModel, and inserted a call to `fireIntervalAdded()` after I queued a new item.  **It works!**  One curiosity is the number of times `getSize()` is called -- e.g., right after calling `addListDataListener()`, JList (or someone) calls `getSize()` 45 times in rapid succession!  Is that to be expected?

Comment: @Chap: Yes, `BasicListUI` invokes `getSize()` frequently to establish the view geometry.

Answer (score 1):

For `JList`, you *don't* have to use `DefaultListModel`, just some implementation of the `ListModel` interface. And the latter is very achievable using a `Deque`.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't know what to do for `addListDataListener()`

[`AbstractListModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) might be a good starting point, as it already implements the prescribed [`EventListenerList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) methods to deal with listeners and events.

Comment: This was indeed the best approach for me, as a beginner.  It drew attention to the existence of the `EventListenerList` and the process of informing the listeners, without requiring me to implement those details right at first.